# 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name '0'

Tags: mysql

it's about the following command:

```sql
INSERT INTO Frequenzen
        (date, hour, name, calibrated_value, rangeofinfluence, stationary)
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
            SELECT '2022-01-01','0','name1','0','123','456') as TEMP
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1 
                    FROM Frequenzen 
                    WHERE date='2022-01-01' 
                    AND hour='0' 
                    AND name='name1'
                    )
```

As soon as a value duplicates, like calibrated_value and hours = 0, I get this error. However, in this case it is not a column name, but the column value. I hope someone can give me a hint. I've been searching the internet for a few days now.

Comment: No need to do a select * from (...), just use the inner query directly. The issue is caused by using a derived table with no field aliases, so the literal values become the field names.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to manage duplicates by creating a unique index on the table?

Comment: thx @ Shadow, it works